# What exactly is the rate limit for editing your own posts?

Tags: support, edits, rate-limiting

According to the [complete guide on rate-limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/377214), users are limited to editing only five of their own posts per day, plus an undisclosed number that increases with their reputation.

What exactly is this rate limit? How many more edits to my own posts can I make for each bit of reputation I earn?

Comment: Is this the rule you're talking about? `You have already edited 5 of your own posts today; further edits are not allowed until tomorrow`?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that's the one.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer to that question but I do know why you posted it (without naming names). Maybe opening multiple posts at the same time and saving the edits within seconds of each other bypassed the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you attempt to make an edit to one of your own posts, the system will allow it if any of the following things are true:

- The number of edits to your own posts you've already made today, which are eligible for the rate limit (see below), is at or below the site's set limit (currently set to 10 across all sites on the network).
- You are a diamond moderator.
- You have the [moderator tools privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).
- The post you are attempting to edit was made within the current or previous UTC day.

If all these criteria fail, you will be blocked from editing for the remainder of the UTC day. The UTC day means literally the current day regardless of the time of day and does not represent a 24-hour rolling day. The block is also effective regardless of whether the post being edited would not qualify for increasing the count per the secondary criteria below.

When counting edits towards the rate limit, unique posts (meaning multiple edits to the same post do not count multiple times) are counted when:

- The post was edited by you in the current UTC day.
- The post was not created on the current or previous UTC day.
- The post has a score of 0 or greater.
- The post is not deleted.

For question edits, all forms of editing (body, title, or tags) count as an edit. Rollbacks do not count as edits for this check and are not blocked if you hit the rate limit.

Comment: One of the bullets conflicts with your [prior answer yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367539/377214). This post says that posts scoring 0 don't count toward the limit, but the other answer says that they *do* (it says "greater than 0", which excludes posts scoring 0). Which is correct?

Comment: @Sonic My mistake. It is 0 or greater, inclusive.